# php and xml does not work simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Hello I have been trying a lot of loading xml via php but from my vps error log I always got error.

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Trying to get
>   property of non-object

So far this what I have created

```
xml.php
<?php

$url = "test.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mypassw0rd");
mysql_select_db("test_xml",$con) or die(mysql_error());

foreach($xml -> item as $row){
    $title = $row -> title;
    $destination = $row -> destination;
    $price = $row -> price;


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tblxml` VALUES('NULL','$title','$destination','$price')") or die(mysql_error());

}

?>
```

test.xml

```
<item>
    <title>
    title 1
    </title>

    <destination>
    destination 1
    </destination>

    <price>
    price 1
    </price>
</item>
```

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblxml` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text NOT NULL,     
  `destination` text NOT NULL,
  `price` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

xml and php both on the same folder.

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: If this is really your xml file and not just an extract, you need to use `$title = $xml->title;` as the `<item>` is just the container. Additionally, there is no list/array to loop over. Furthermore, the `mysql_` functions have been deprecated some centuries ago, please use the newer `mysqli_` - functions or `PDO` (do they have text blocks on SO, so that you do not have to type this everytime ;-)) ?

Answer (score 0):

Having read your question again, there are really a couple of serious flaws with it.

1. Please read a good tutorial on XML/SimpleXML/DomDocument
2. As mentionned, use the newer `mysqli_` functions, `PDO` and binding
3. What's the purpose of fetchting an XML file locally with `curl` ?
4. Your query won't work, you did not specify the fields and you do not need to insert `NULL` values (though it will work). This is the skeleton for an `INSERT` query in `MySQL`:

> ```
> INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`, ..., `fieldx`) VALUES('$value1', ... '$valuex');
> ```